# Histogram of my cam in real time

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

Im trying to show the histogram in real time from grayscale of my webcam, the problem is that histogram is not being update and my cam stop until i close histogram's window. How can i fix this? I want to show the grayscale img from my webcam and its histogram in same time, is possible do that?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Janela', frame)
    cv2.imshow('Outra', gray)
    plt.hist(gray.ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
    plt.show()

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `plt.show()` opens a windows that blocks unlike `cv2.imshow` which requires `cv2.waitkey` to block. So showing the histogram using a different function is your best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working for a while in the same task. After some time, I have a piece of code that works very good. It displays the camera image in a window and a histogram in other. Since I'm interested in finding colors, I'm working with the "hue" channel of each frame.

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Create window to display image
cv2.namedWindow('colorhist', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

#Set hist parameters
hist_height = 64
hist_width = 256
nbins = 32
bin_width = hist_width/nbins

camera_id = 0 # type fo webcam [0 built-in | 1 external]
cameraWidth = 320
cameraHeight = 240

if camera_id == 0:
   cameraId = "PC webcam"
elif camera_id == 1:
   cameraId = "External webcam"

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)

# set camera image to 320 x 240 pixels
camera.set(3,cameraWidth)
camera.set(4,cameraHeight)

cameraInfo = "Image size (%d,%d)" % (camera.get(3),camera.get(4))

# initialize mask matrix
mask = np.zeros((cameraHeight,cameraWidth),  np.uint8)

# draw a circle in mask matrix
cv2.circle(mask,(cameraWidth/2,cameraHeight/2), 50, 255, -1)

#Create an empty image for the histogram
h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width))

#Create array for the bins
bins = np.arange(nbins,dtype=np.int32).reshape(nbins,1)

while True:
   # grab the current frame 
   (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

   if not grabbed:
      "Camera could not be started."
      break

   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   #Calculate and normalise the histogram
   hist_hue = cv2.calcHist([hsv],[0],mask,[nbins],[0,256])
   cv2.normalize(hist_hue,hist_hue,hist_height,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
   hist=np.int32(np.around(hist_hue))
   pts = np.column_stack((bins,hist))

   #Loop through each bin and plot the rectangle in white
   for x,y in enumerate(hist):
      cv2.rectangle(h,(x*bin_width,y),(x*bin_width + bin_width-1,hist_height),(255),-1)

   #Flip upside down
   h=np.flipud(h)

   #Show the histogram
   cv2.imshow('Color Histogram',h)
   h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width))

   frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask)
   cv2.putText(frame, cameraInfo, (10, 20),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

   cv2.imshow(cameraId, frame)            
   key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

   # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the loop
   if key == ord("q"):
      break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code is based on the code from JohnLinux post ([How do I plot a 32-Bin Histogram for a Grayscale Image in Python using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203388/how-do-i-plot-a-32-bin-histogram-for-a-grayscale-image-in-python-using-opencv)) and other lines of code come from what I have learnt from Adrian Rosenbrock's site https://www.pyimagesearch.com/.

Comment: Exactly this i was trying to do! I just had to cast some variables to int, because was giving error type.  `` cv2.circle(mask,(cameraWidth/2,cameraHeight/2), 50, 255, -1)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float´´

Answer (score 3):

I see there is very little feedback on this topic. Some solutions look overwhelmingly complex. My brother needed just a simple version of such programme for his studies, so I decided to write it as simple as it can be (11 lines of code - enjoy:))

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

vid = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW)
while True:
    ret, img = vid.read()
    cv.imshow("img", img)
    plt.hist(img.ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.clf()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution for the picamera doing stream + histogram

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 40
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    bgr_arr = frame.array 
    gray_arr = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    cv2.imshow("Preview", gray_arr)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
    plt.hist(gray_arr.ravel(), 256, [0, 256], histtype='stepfilled')
    plt.title('Grayscale histogram')
    plt.xlabel('Grayscale value')
    plt.ylabel('Pixel count')
    plt.plot()
    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.clf()

    if key == ord("q"):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```